# Cropping ROI regions in an numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing some codes to cut two seprate ROI regions in an numpy array. The array is a mask array with boolean values and it consists of two major left and right parts.

I need to crops those left and right parts from my original numpy array. My codes are as follow which are a section of function (image and masked are passed to this function)

```
if mask.shape[-1] > 0:
    # We're treating all instances as one, so collapse the mask into one layer
    mask = (np.sum(mask, -1, keepdims=True) >= 1)
    zeros=np.zeros(image.shape)
    #splash = np.where(mask, image, gray).astype(np.uint8)
    splash = np.where(mask, image, zeros).astype(np.uint8)
```

I am not sure how to achieve this as I am really new to bumpy. I can splash the imge but what I need is differt I ned to crop two left and right parts and for this I need to crop or reshape the mask array. I have attached a splashed output sample to this thread

[image: bumpy splashed image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very typical problem in computer vision. One popular solution to this is the Connected Component Labeling (or CCL). OpenCV has already an implementation for this:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaedef8c7340499ca391d459122e51bef5

Then you may use blob analysis to crop out the objects:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html